# Invalid column name 'saleStatus_id'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using migration I created a table called **sale_status**

```
public class SaleStatus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private short id;
    private String description;
```

and **make_sale**

```
public class MakeSale {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL")
    private String detail;
    @Column(name = "application_date")
    private java.time.LocalDateTime applicationDate;
    @OneToOne
    private SaleStatus SaleStatus;
```

Currently, I have **sale_status_id** in the table but it is asking for **saleStatus_id** The field names have all underscores but when I try to insert data I get the above error. How can I solve this?

The error detail is

```
[nio-8085-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name 'SaleStatus_id'.
2021-08-31 14:03:34.099 ERROR 42928 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet]
```

Comment: I don't see any error message above. Can you add.
And also in in SaleStatus table your Id field's name is just 'Id', it would generate table column with 'id'.
You can rename id field as 'saleStatusId'

Comment: You forgot to include the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a relationship is created, JPA maps it with a standard naming convention. If you need to name a column otherwise, you can always tell JPA how it is called. In your case, you can add some informations:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sale_status_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private SaleStatus SaleStatus;
```

Comment: This perfectly solved the problem thank you.